# Paraphrasing "Hours of leisure time per year in Someland"

Tags: grammar, paraphrasing

I'm getting ready for the IELTS exam (The academic module) and as some of you might know , in the writing section (Task 1) we will be given a graph. Take a look at the picture below as an example:

[image]

For the introduction part of the writing we must "paraphrase" the original title of the given graph . I mean we have to paraphrase "Hours of leisure time per year in Someland". What I have in mind is below text :

> *The given table provides information on numbers of hours people with different age group spend on leisure activities per year in Someland*

I was wondering of you could tell me if there is anything wrong with the grammar or the meaning? Or do you have better ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of meaning, your paraphrase seems good. However, the grammar needs a little work.

> The given table provides information about the number of hours people in
> different age groups spend on leisure activities in Someland per year.

I changed:

> numbers of hours to *the number of hours*
>
> with different age group to *in different age groups*